# attempt to invoke virtual method java lang String split

Tags: java, android-studio

the code is trying to read a comma delimited text file

this is the code that is giving the error

```
while((PlaceHold = in.readLine())!=null){
            PlaceHold = in.readLine();
            String[]Split = PlaceHold.split(Delimit);
            db.Restaurant1.setFoodName(Split[0]);
            db.Restaurant1.setCarbs(Split[1]);
            db.Restaurant1.setServingSize(Split[2]);
            db.addRestaurant(new DBLocationHelp.Restaurant(Split[0], Split[1], Split[2]));
        }
```

and this is the error it gives

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.diabeticdiner/com.example.diabeticdiner.Arby}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Remove the line `PlaceHold = in.readLine();` inside the loop.

Comment: You should use Java naming conventions: variables start with lowercase letters: `placeHold`, `split`, `delimit` etc.